# Symbolic link for log files on AIX

Tags: symbolic-link, aix

I have an AIX 5.3 and I need to point the `/var/mylogs/trace` directory at another `/mydir/temp`

When I use the symbolic link syntax;

```
ln -s /mydir/temp /var/mylogs/trace
```

In `/var/mylogs/trace` I get a directory named temp that links to `/mydir/temp`. So I need to use `/var/mylogs/trace/temp` to get to the temp directory. I need to redirect without the need for a further entry in the path.

`cd /var/mylogs/trace` should show me the contents of `/mydir/temp`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by renaming the old trace dir.

```
mv trace traceold
ln -s /mydir/temp /var/mylogs/trace
```